# How to raise click event of button which is in the popup?

Tags: c#, wpf

Usercontrol's template is as below.

```
 <ControlTemplate x:Key="MarkerTemplate"  >
        <ToggleButton x:Name="btnMarkerPin" Click="btnMarkerPin_Click" >
            <ToggleButton.Template>
                <ControlTemplate >
                    <Grid>
                    <Grid>
                        <Ellipse Fill="Green" Width="25" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ToolTip="{Binding}" />
        </Grid>
                    <Popup x:Name="pop" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=pin}" StaysOpen="True" Placement="Top" VerticalOffset="-4" HorizontalOffset="-4" IsOpen="False" Margin="30,-50,0,0" AllowsTransparency="True" >
                        <Border Opacity=".7" CornerRadius="5" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2" Background="Yellow">
                            <Grid Margin="10">
                                    <Button x:Name="btnLinkMarker" Style="{StaticResource LinkButton}"  FontWeight="Bold" Content="{Binding}" />
                                </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="pop" Property="IsOpen" Value="true"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ToggleButton.Template>               
        </ToggleButton>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Click should happen on btnLinkMarker in popup. If i raise event i get an exception object reference not set. Can anyone help. How do i raise this event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a [Command](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22270/WPF-Commands) to a button and call **Command** and *not* raise an event on the control (`UI` artifact).

In WPF **always** avoid acting directly on `UI`, as much as it possible. Here, at least in provided question context, it's something that can be easilly achieved.

[What are Commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx)

Comment: @Ershad: mark this as a correct answer, if you are confident this is  a right solution for **you**. In my personal opinion, yes.